# SQLError could not prepare statement

Tags: angularjs, sqlite

Hi Im trying to dynamically ORDER BY my sqlite in angular. but it always says erro rcould not prepare statement..  and it redirect to my order string.. But when I manually set my ASC or DESC it works pretty well. My question is how can I set my string to my query

This is my js.  The order_by_field is equal to the name and the order is equal to the ASC or DESC

```
//Sort Priority Ascending
            $scope.sortAsc = function() {
                sort_orderby('name', 'asc');
                $scope.orderByPopover.hide();
            };

            //Sort Priority Descending
            $scope.sortDesc = function() {
                sort_orderby('name', 'desc');
                $scope.orderByPopover.hide();
            };

            function sort_orderby(order_by_field, order) {

                var query = "SELECT * FROM listJobs ORDER BY '" + order_by_field + "' '"+ order +"' ";
                $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, [])
                    //If success
                    .then(function(data) {

                            offlineGetJobList();
                            console.log(data.rows)
                        },
                        function(err) {
                            console.error(err);
                        });



            }
```

Comment: Please do a `console.log` for `query` and post the result.

Comment: try removing the single quotes from the query.

Comment: @31piy This is my result SELECT * FROM listJobs ORDER BY 'priority' 'asc'.. But when I followed jayvee advise it works a charm :D.. Thanks jayvee. Ithink it become string when i add the single quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM listJobs ORDER BY '" + order_by_field + "' '"+ order +"' ";
```

should be

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM listJobs ORDER BY " + order_by_field + " "+ order +" ";
```